# How do i secure my Google Maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I read in the Google help that I have to setup some `proxy` on my own server for this.

I don't have my own server and doing just learning programming through apps. I have an app ready which uses API for `DirectionServices`.

Is just turning on `ProGuard` sufficient or should I do more?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've found out that using ProGuard is sufficient for most independent developers. If you are running an enterprise system obviously you need to setup a proxy and let you requests run through them